# C: playing audio loops in linux

Tags: c, linux, audio

I have a buffer of `int16_t` with some audio PCM data in it. I need to play the buffer repetitively from a point a to a point b, so that you hear an infinite audio loop.

I found that the easiest way to play sound is by using libao, but I agree with any other method.
This is my code:

```
int play(int a, int b, char *buf);

int main()
{
        int16_t *buf;  /*my buffer*/
        int a, b;
        /* a and b are the indexes of the buffer; 
         * because libao wants a buffer of char, 
         * and buf points to of int16_t, I'll pass 
         * the value a and b multiplied with 2.
         */ 

        [···]

        play(2*a, 2*b, (char *) buf);
        return 0;
}
int play(int a, int b, char *buf)
{  
        ao_device *device;  
        ao_sample_format format;  
        int default_driver;   
        /* -- Initialize -- */
        fprintf(stderr, "libao example program\n");  
        ao_initialize();  
        /* -- Setup for default driver -- */  
        default_driver = ao_default_driver_id();  
        memset(&format, 0, sizeof(format));  
        format.bits = 16;  
        format.channels = 1;  
        format.rate = 44100;  
        format.byte_format = AO_FMT_LITTLE;
        /* -- Open driver -- */  
        device = ao_open_live(default_driver, &format, NULL /* no options */);  
        if (device == NULL) {  
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening device.\n");  
            exit(1);  
        }  
        /* -- Play the infinite loop -- */
        for (;;){
            ao_play(device, buf+a, b-a+1);
            /*buf+a is the start of the loop, b-a+1 the number of byte to play--edited*/
        }
        /* -- Close and shutdown -- */  
        ao_close(device);  
        ao_shutdown();  
    return 0;  
}
```

The problem is that I hear a period of silence between the end and the start of the loop. Because I'm using this code to testing other code, I absolutely need to know if it could be caused by an incorrect use of [libao](https://www.xiph.org/ao/doc/).

Comment: I always thought the easiest way to do sound in Linux was just to pipe to `/dev/snd` :)

Comment: It seems that it is no more allowed in recent kernels, because of problems of security. I'm using Debian 6.0.6 and kernel 2.6.32-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely could be caused by incorrect use of libao.  Please remove the +1 from the ao_play() call, like so:

```
ao_play(device, buf+a, b-a);
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. So this means that the "Number of bytes of audio data in the memory buffer" (the third argument) is esclused the first?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but I'll try to explain anyway. The third argument specifies how many BYTES ao should play from the given buffer. Bytes however are not the same as frames, and currently ao cannot play "half a sample" or anything like that. So the argument must be a multiple of your frame size (sample size in bytes * channel count).  If your frames are two bytes and you add one to pass n frames plus one byte, ao will lose half-a-frame and the next time you call ao_play, the samples are misaligned internally, causing silence (or noise!). Next call aligns them back again.

Comment: I was wrong, because the problem persists. I made a testing package (http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/404492/loop-test-tar-gz.html). compile with "gcc -lao stack_overflow.c" and run with "./a.out test.wav". Either with 'b-a' or 'b-a+1' there is a silence moment between the end and the start of the loop.